# Node.js 404 errors when emailing, ignores my res.status

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, nodemailer

I have a angular app with form that makes ajax request. Emailing works fine but no matter what I set response to; I get an error for the path. I assume node expects the path '/send' to render a template or data but I just want the path to email!~ I use a modal pop-up for the form & angular ui-routing for paths.

```
app.get('/send', function (req, res, err) { 
  var cartContent = req.body.slice(1,20);
  var content = tableify(cartContent);
  var sendit = {
    to: '*****@gmail.com',
    from: '****@bluenightphoto.com',
    replyTo: req.body[0].email,

    subject: "CP Carpet Quote Request: " + req.body[0].fname + " " + req.body[0].lname , // REQUIRED.

    html: '<b>Customer Quote</b>' + '<br>' + 'Customer Name: ' + req.body[0].fname + " " +
    '<br>' + 'Message: ' + req.body[0].message + '<br>' + <b>Table</b>'+ '<br><br>' + content,
  };

  // Transporter refers to nodemailer and sendit is the login details(mail works fine!)

  transporter.sendMail(sendit, function (req, res, err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err + "something strange...");
      res.status(401).send("that's all folk's");
    } else {
      res.status(200).send("nuthing here");
      console.log("Message sent! " );
    }

    transporter.close();
  });
});
```

Yet my error handler always gets a 404 response instead even if emailing is successful.

EDIT: tried the two solutions below, did not work.

Here is the angular ajax code

```
var makeForm = function () {
                if (mailJson[1].total !== 0) {
                    deferred.resolve(mailJson);
                    console.log('values loaded successfully again');


                    $http({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : '/send',
                        data : mailJson,
                        headers : {
                            'Content-type' : 'application/json'
                        }
                    }).success(function () {
                        console.log('success!');
                        $scope.alertEmailOk = true;
                    }).error(function (err) {
                        console.log('there was an error indeed ' + err);
                        $scope.alertEmailOk = false;
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('no values!');
                    deferred.reject(mailJson);
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            };
```

console.log('there was an error indeed ' + err); always fires..maybe I need to send data back?

Here's the error handler in my express code:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {

    // changes it to use the optimized version for production
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You're getting bit by async, but I'm pretty sure we're missing an important bit of code here. Anything else in that route controller? Also, the middleware is `(req, res, next)`

Comment: Is it related to `angularjs`? If it is out of the equation -- then remove the tag to hide it from brains hungry for `angularjs`.

Comment: I added the angular ajax code.

Comment: Are you sending a success back at all? 200 isn't enough i think.

Comment: See my answers below. Originally just got 404 or 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transporter.sendMail(sendit,function(error, info){
if (error) {
    console.log(error + "something strange...");
    }

console.log("Message sent!");
});

    res.send("Messaage was Sent");

return next();
});
```

This worked. Trying to set the res.send object inside transporter function caused it not to fire. Placing it outside allowed it to fine and now I have zero errors.

Comment: And for now have you got an issue ? or all is working like you want ?

Comment: No issue, it solved it 100%.. I'm very surprised I coulding get res.send to work inside the transporter.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Transporter refers to nodemailer and sendit is the login details(mail works fine!)
```

I have read your comment, but first of all let be sure of this next part :
From [nodemailer](http://nodemailer.com/)

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'sender@gmail.com',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});
var sendIt = { //<------ i've just renamed this compare to nodemailer.com sample 
    from: 'sender@address',
    to: 'receiver@address',
    subject: 'hello',
    text: 'hello world!'
};


// this part is very important !
// note the signature.
transporter.sendMail(sendIt, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);

});
```

so now trying to insert that in your code :

```js
//app.get('/send', function (req, res, err) { 
app.get('/send', function (req, res, next) { 

  var cartContent = req.body.slice(1,20);
  var content = tableify(cartContent);
  var sendit = {
    to: '*****@gmail.com',
    from: '****@bluenightphoto.com',
    replyTo: req.body[0].email,

    subject: "CP Carpet Quote Request: " + req.body[0].fname + " " + req.body[0].lname , // REQUIRED.

    html: '<b>Customer Quote</b>' + '<br>' + 'Customer Name: ' + req.body[0].fname + " " +
    '<br>' + 'Message: ' + req.body[0].message + '<br>' + <b>Table</b>'+ '<br><br>' + content,
  };

  // Transporter refers to nodemailer and sendit is the login details(mail works fine!)
  //     |                 
  //     |
  //     v
  // Transporter refers to the login details and sendit to the mail options


  transporter.sendMail(sendit, function (error, info) {// instead of (req, res, err) {
    if (error) { // instead of err just to avoid colision name
      console.log(error + "something strange...");
      res.status(401).send("that's all folk's");
    } else {
      res.status(200).send("nuthing here");
      console.log("Message sent! " );
    }

    transporter.close();
  });

return next();
});
```

in your code, your issue was here :

```
transporter.sendMail(  sendit, function (  req, res, err)  {
//transporter.sendMail(sendit, function (error, info) {

    if (err) { 
      console.log(err + "something strange...");
      res.status(401).send("that's all folk's");

      // you are acting here on the 'info' coming from transporter.sendMail
     // not on 'res' from app.get('/send',      


    } else {
      res.status(200).send("nuthing here");
      console.log("Message sent! " );


      // you are acting here on the 'info' coming from transporter.sendMail
     // not on 'res' from app.get('/send',      

    }
```

Try this change above your issue explication, i hope it will solve your problem. :-)

Comment: Didn't work, I added my error handler and ajax angular code to original question.

Comment: what happen if you replace `return next();` by just calling it whitout return it`next();`

Comment: I gave you bounty, your answer lead me in the right direction

Comment: Great! Thank you, I am very pleased to have been able to help you ! :-))

Answer (score 0):

Here are some fixes and comments:

```
app.get('/send', function (req, res, next) {
  // ...
  transporter.sendMail(sendit, function (req, res, next) { // Asynchronous = do it later.
    // Parent arg `res` is masked by another `res` which is passed by `sendMail`.
    // I don't know if `sendMail` passes the same one or some other `res`.
    // You may try renaming it to `res2`.
  }
  return next(); // For now call next middleware, all async code will be executed later.
```